# Relative Layout not compiling!

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

I was trying to do an adapter on a ListView as an exercise but I get a strange error on the row layout:

```
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

What is wrong with this very simple Layout??!?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/station"
        android:text="Stazione DI"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <TextView 
        androdi:id="@+id/time"
        android:text="Time:"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:below="@id/station"/>


    <TextView 
        androdi:id="+id/late"
        android:text="Time:"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"
        android:below="@id/station"/>




    <TextView 
        androdi:id="+id/rail"
        android:text="Rail:"
        android:below="@id/station"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/late"/>







  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prefixes are those strings you type before the `:`, like `android:...`. And you typed it wrong once (`androdi:...`)

(edit: actually 3 times)

Comment: I also forgot the @ in id declaration and used the tag "below" instead of "layout_below".... still learning :P

Answer (score 1):

Prefixes in Last TextView spell not correct, check that

Answer (score 0):

In xml file last Textview is worong

```
<TextView 
  androdi:id="+id/rail"
  android:text="Rail:"
  android:below="@id/station"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/late"/>
```

It will be

```
<TextView 
 android:id="+id/rail"
 android:text="Rail:"
 android:below="@id/station"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/late"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have written android spelling wrong in following cases !

```
androdi:id="@+id/time"
androdi:id="+id/late"
androdi:id="+id/rail"
```